# How to check uncheck checkboxes inside nested gridview using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Actually, I implemented half of the code like if one checkbox is checked then check all checkboxes under that checkbox.

But now I want to uncheck the main checkbox if I marked uncheck on other checkboxes too...

please help me appropriate with this...

my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SelectAllCheckboxesA(chk, chk1, chk2, chk3, chk4) {
        document.getElementById(chk1).checked = document.getElementById(chk2).checked = document.getElementById(chk3).checked = document.getElementById(chk4).checked = document.getElementById(chk).checked;
        if (document.getElementById(chk1).checked == false || document.getElementById(chk2).checked == false || document.getElementById(chk3).checked == false || document.getElementById(chk4).checked == false) document.getElementById(chk).checked = false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What has this got to do with C#?

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a css class to the parent check box and and another class for all the children it will be easier.

```
<html>
   <body>
      <br><br>
      <input type="checkbox" class="parent" name="vehicle" > Parent<br>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="vehicle"> child 1<br>
      <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="vehicle"> child 2<br>
      <input type="checkbox" class="child" name="vehicle"> child 3<br>
      <script type="text/javascript">
     var parentCheckBox = document.querySelector(".parent");
     var childCheckBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".child");
     parentCheckBox.onclick = function(){
         childCheckBoxes.forEach(function(child){
        child.checked=parentCheckBox.checked;
         });
     }
     childCheckBoxes.forEach(function(child){
        child.onclick = function(){ 
      var allchecked = true;
         childCheckBoxes.forEach(function(childBox){       
           allchecked = allchecked? childBox.checked : allchecked;       
         });
           parentCheckBox.checked = allchecked;
         } 
     });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is the demo https://jsfiddle.net/m23txgdz/

Comment: Thank you so much.. actually this solution is really helpful. but, in my case i am using nested gridview so how does  this work for that.. do i need to loop my checkboxes or what?

Comment: @swati: When your page is ready or grid is loaded, declare two arrays parentCheckBox and ChildCheckBoxes.  Store the main check box in ParentCheckBox and dependent check boxes in childCheckBoxes array. Then run the above code. Eg: parentCheckBox = [chk] , childCheckBoxes = [chk1,chk2,chk3,chk4].